# PHP Single Quote Regex for Text in the First Line

Tags: php, regex, mediawiki-api

I have a wiki website (MediaWiki) and I need to extract some plain text from the first line of each wiki article page. The First line of each wiki article page has text that I want but the text is inside wiki markup tags, for example:

```
$text = "Text that I DO NOT want '''Text that I do want, inside wiki tags''' text that I DO NOT want";
```

I've figured out the PHP regex to get the text up to the end of the first line:

```
if(preg_match("/^.*/", $text, $match)){
  echo "<br>This is the text in the first line of the wiki article page: ".$match[0];
}
```

I need to combine the `/^.*/` expression above with the PHP regex to find only the text inside the `'''` wiki tags.  And I'm having trouble doing this. 
Can someone help me with this?  Also how do I  escape the `'''` single quotes?
Thanks for all your help.

Peter

Comment: Have you tried the [TextExtracts extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:TextExtracts) web API?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$parts = explode("'''",$text,3);
$part_you_want = $parts[1];
```

This is much cheaper than using regexes, and hopefully less confusing too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$text = "Text that I DO NOT want '''Text that I do want, inside wiki tags''' text that I DO NOT want";
if(preg_match("/'''(.*)'''/", $text, $match)){
  echo "<br>This is the text in the first line of the wiki article page: ".$match[1];
}
```

Comment: I'd make that ungreedy to avoid confustion with longer strings / repeated `'''`

Comment: Hi,                                                               Thanks for all your replies and advice. I finally figured it out and settled on a look around regex: /(?<=\'\'\').*?(?=\'\'\')/
I found it in another stack discussion (Thank you to Bart for the helpful info) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411799/regex-expert-php-lookaround